# Include a jquery library if it doesnt exist

Tags: javascript

I have 5000 JSP pages in my application in which 2500 pages have jquery library included in them. So still I have 2500 JSP which doesn't have it I cannot add manually in all those files I want a piece of code either in JavaScript or java which should check whether src="jquery/jquery-generic.js" this already exists or not.If not then I need to add it.

I have some functions which are included in all JSP pages so I have added this script code from that function but it is breaking my system because in some pages I have these functions after all the libraries are included. so there are some features which are depended on my jquery so I code I wrote is overriding the code which already existing and when the other libraries which are depended on that are not working.

ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-generic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/hoverIntent.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/superfish.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/superfish-vertical.css">
<link type="text/css" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>
................................
.................................
at some point my functions are adding the the library again
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-generic.js"></script>
so all the above functions are not working.
```

can anyone have an idea how to check whether already code exists or not if not add it?

Comment: Never mind I got the solution to this problem

Comment: For jsp it's not good to have much scripts on the page.